# Docker TensorFlow project

Tags: docker, tensorflow, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I am struggling to find a solution to deploy a recommendation system using containers.

**Scenario** -- I have built a TensorFlow model and a Django API server on top of that. 
- The model is saved on disk. 
- APi requests are related to new users, new items and new user/item interactions.
 - All these API requests load the model from disk, re-train the model with new information and return the updated predictions.

**Problem** -- I want to containerize this thing to run on Azure App Services under Web App for Containers. The problem i am facing is that how can i have persistent volumes along container to keep the saved model there?

TO my knowledge, i have two options -

- Use Azure Blob Storage to store all the model files - But not sure if this will work with TensorFlow.
- Use the container volumes as is. - But i am afraid if do a release pipeline to destroy the container and push the new container to production, it will delete all the model files and the volumes will be re-created.

I am pretty lost in this space right now with no clear idea how to approach a good option.